# Change json values in powershell using if statements

Tags: json, powershell, if-statement, foreach

I have been trying to recreate what I've done manually into if statements. Outside the if statements and for loops the powershell scripts work fine alone to change json values, however once incorporated into what you see here it doesn't work. It will change the depth of the file but nothing else.

The point of the script is to replace the values in a json file at specific nodes at $Jsondata.$nodes.

Many thanks.

json file example

```
{
    "Host": {
        "Server": "www.server1.com"
        "Server.Author": "sbt.lop.wys"
        "Server:Temp": "hesus.com"
        }
}
```

```
$Server1 = "C:\\home\file1.json"
$Server2 = "C:\\home\file2.json"
$Server3 = "C:\\home\file3.json"

$JsonFilePath = ($Server1, $Server2, $Server3)

foreach($filepath in %JsonFilePath) {
    if ($filepath -eq $Server1) {
        $nodes = "Host.Server"
        $Jsondata = Get-Content $filepath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        $JsonData.update | % {if($JsonData.$nodes) 
            {
                $Jsondata.$nodes = "www.blabla.com"
            }
        }
        $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32 | Set-Content $filepath
        
    elseif ($filepath -eq $Server2) {
        $nodes = "Host.Server.Author"
        $Jsondata = Get-Content $filepath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        $JsonData.update | % {if($JsonData.$nodes) 
            {
                $Jsondata.$nodes = "www.blabla.com"
            }
        }
        $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32 | Set-Content $filepath
        
    elseif ($filepath -eq $Server3) {
        $nodes = ("Host.Server", "Host.Server:Temp")
        $Jsondata = Get-Content $filepath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
        foreach($node in $nodes){
        $JsonData.update | % {if($JsonData.$nodes) 
            {
                $Jsondata.$nodes = "www.blabla.com"
            }
        }
        $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32 | Set-Content $filepath
    }
```

Update:

After running the file, all i get is this, nothing has been changed:

```
{
    "Host":     {
                "Server": "www.server1.com"
                "Server.Author": "sbt.lop.wys"
                "Server:Temp": "hesus.com"
            }
}
```

I have also done `write-host $Jsondata.$nodes` and nothing is shown in the console, however `write-host $nodes` and `write-host $filepath` all show the correct text. I'm not sure why nothing is getting passed into $Jsondata.$nodes or i am missing a step here? It worked fine manually outside all the loops.

Comment: Please be more elaborate than "it doesn't work". Show us _what happens_ (eg. the incorrect JSON output) and describe how it conflicts with your expectations

Comment: Apologies, I have added what I've tried doing with th results